# how to query jsonb field with arrays inside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql-9.4

i have a jsonb field which have an array like this

```
[{"odd_id"=>"5328", "team_id"=>"", "event_id"=>"10301952", "odd_type"=>"full_time", "odd_label"=>"X", "odd_value"=>"3.29"}, {"odd_id"=>"5349", "team_id"=>"", "event_id"=>"10299004", "odd_type"=>"full_time", "odd_label"=>"X", "odd_value"=>"3.10"}, {"odd_id"=>"5237", "team_id"=>"2554", "event_id"=>"2020445", "odd_type"=>"full_time", "odd_label"=>"1", "odd_value"=>"2.87"}, {"odd_id"=>"5174", "team_id"=>"669", "event_id"=>"1685560", "odd_type"=>"full_time", "odd_label"=>"2", "odd_value"=>"3.39"}]
```

i want to use the where to query the event_id in the column.
can someone direct me in right direction on how to archive this, by the way am using Rails 5 and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume you've model called `Test` with jsonb field `test_field`, where one particular value is array of hash, as shown:

```
[{"odd_id"=>"5328", "team_id"=>"", "event_id"=>"10301952", "odd_type"=>"full_time", "odd_label"=>"X", "odd_value"=>"3.29"}, {"odd_id"=>"5349", "team_id"=>"", "event_id"=>"10299004", "odd_type"=>"full_time", "odd_label"=>"X", "odd_value"=>"3.10"}, {"odd_id"=>"5237", "team_id"=>"2554", "event_id"=>"2020445", "odd_type"=>"full_time", "odd_label"=>"1", "odd_value"=>"2.87"}, {"odd_id"=>"5174", "team_id"=>"669", "event_id"=>"1685560", "odd_type"=>"full_time", "odd_label"=>"2", "odd_value"=>"3.39"}]
```

You've to query the database like:

`Test.where('test_field @> ?', [{ 'event_id' => '10301952' }].to_json)`

Comment: @geniuskidkanyi I thought it was just an json, didn't see the array. Edited the answer as per your need.